# error al verificar si hay un usuario repetido a través de un mensaje en php y sql

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

tengo un procedimiento almacenado de registrar, donde pongo una condición si es que no hay correo ni dni repetido se pueda registrar y me imprima el número 1 y desde php pongo una condición para que si al momento de registrarme trato de hacer la comparación con el número para que me imprima el mensaje correcto, cuando lo hago con mysql no tengo problemas, pero ahora lo estoy haciendo con sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRegistrarUsuario] @utipoDoc int, @unroDoc varchar(100) ,@unombres varchar(300),@uapellidos  varchar(300),@udireccion  varchar(500),
                                    @ucorreo varchar(200),@ucontrasena varchar(200),@utelCel varchar(100), @ufechaRegistro varchar(200)
                                
as
BEGIN
        declare @vcorreo int,  @vnroDoc int , @vrespuesta int

        set @vcorreo = (select count(*) from usuario where correo = @ucorreo);
        set @vnroDoc = (select count(*) from usuario where nroDoc = @unroDoc);


        if(@vcorreo = 0) and (@vnroDoc = 0) 
        begin
        insert into usuario (tipoDoc,nroDoc,nombres,apellidos,direccion,correo,contrasena,telCel,fechaRegistro)
        values (@utipoDoc,@unroDoc,@unombres,@uapellidos,@udireccion,@ucorreo,@ucontrasena,@utelCel,@ufechaRegistro);
        set @vrespuesta = 1;
        end
        select @vrespuesta as respuesta;
END
```

Mi controlador

```
static public function ctrCrearUsuario()
    {

        if (isset($_POST["nuNroDoc"])) {

            $datos = array(

                "u_tipoDoc" => trim($_POST["nuTipoDoc"]),
                "u_nroDoc" => trim($_POST["nuNroDoc"]),
                "u_correo" => trim($_POST["nuCorreo"]),
            );

            $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlRegistrarUsuario($datos);
            if ($respuesta["respuesta"] == 1) {
                echo '<script>

                swal({
                    type: "success",
                    title: "¡Registro exitoso!"

                }).then(function(result){

                    if(result.value){
                        window.location = "login";
                    }

                });

                </script>';
            } else {
             
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es el codigo de mi modelo en php

```
 static public function mdlRegistrarUsuario($datos)
    {
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("exec spRegistrarUsuario :tipoDoc,:nroDoc,:nombres,
        :apellidos,:direccion,:correo,:contrasena,:telCel,:fechaRegistro");

        $stmt->bindParam(":tipoDoc",  $datos["u_tipoDoc"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":nroDoc",  $datos["u_nroDoc"], 
        $stmt->bindParam(":correo",  $datos["u_correo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":telCel",  $datos["u_telCel"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":fechaRegistro",  $datos["u_fechaRegistro"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
```

---

Ósea mi procedimiento almacenado si funciona, logro insertar y al momento de insertar me imprime el numero 1 como un select y en mi código php lo que quiero condicionar es cuando me de un select 1, me muestre un mensaje de se Logro registrar y en el else seria lo contrario, en mi codigo publicado es como lo hice en MySql y quisiera repetir algo parecido con sql Server, desde mi código Php si logro registrar, lo que me falta es que me muestre el mensaje correcto

[image: Cuando logro registrar desde el sql]

Comment: A qué exactamente le llamas _"imprimir el número 1"_. Pregunto, porque la descripción me parece incorrecta... en realidad no estamos _imprimiendo_ nada en un SP, ¿o si?

Answer (score 0):

No se a que te refieres exactamente, pero al comprobar si un usuario ya existe en la base de datos yo lo hago de esta manera mediante PHP.

```
$statement = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=:id AND email=:email");
$statement -> execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':email'=>$usuario));
$resultado = $statement -> fetch();

if($resultado != false){
  echo "Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cambia el código de SQL por el siguiente

```
declare @id = INT

insert into usuario (tipoDoc,nroDoc,nombres,apellidos,direccion,correo,contrasena,telCel,fechaRegistro)
select @utipoDoc,@unroDoc,@unombres,@uapellidos,@udireccion,@ucorreo,@ucontrasena,@utelCel,@ufechaRegistro
where not exists( select 1 from usuario where @ucorreo = correo or @unroDoc = nroDoc )

select @id = @@scope_identity

select iif(@id is null, 0, 1 )
```